# Re-binding an AngularJS app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jsdom

Presently I'm using NodeJS and JSDOM to pre-render my AngularJS application on my server for Google SEO purposes:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom
  , document = jsdom(template)

// Render Angular App
angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(...)

res.end(document.innerHTML)
```

On the client, I have the angular source code, my controller function, exactly the same as used on the server, but instead of an Angular template app with `{{}}`s I have a rendered angular application with data.

I want the client to pickup where the server left off, but it starts it as a new app so all of the data in my `ng-repeat` is doubled-up.

How can I get Angular to pickup where the server left off and simply re-bind instead of treating it as a new app and rendering?

Comment: This sounds overly complicated. Why do you need to pre-render? If it's not a search engine crawler, just serve the normal Angular app.

Comment: I'd like to avoid code that detects specific crawler engines, as I'd like it to be as timeless as possible. I want to serve the same data to everyone, to avoid the pitfalls of trivial conditional logic.

Comment: I want to know this as well.
I would even be willing to reset everything on the client side, on the first change.
Any answers??